# Nagios Plugin for Dell Desktop RAID

Tags: raid, nagios, dell

Is anyone aware of a plugin for Nagios that will report on the status of the RAID controller on dell Workstations, primarily Dell Precision Workstations, T3400 & T3500?

I'm currently using [this plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Dell/check_dell_openmanage/details), which works fine with Servers, but not workstations, which report unknown for disk status (along with a number of other things). It does pick up something, like Chassis intrusion.

Alternatively, I can probably adapt this script if I can get the OID's for the Dell arrays in these machines, however I'm having a hard time locating these.

Comment: What I usually do for OIDs I don't know is `snmpwalk` the host and then look on [oidview.com](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/detail.html) for the vendor specific MIBs. Take a look at the [Dell MIBs](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/674/md-674-1.html) and see if anything on their list matches your `snmpwalk`

Comment: Which model raid controller is it? What OS are the workstations running?

Comment: @sciurus These are all Windows 7 Machines. The T3500's are running the    
SAS6/iR Intergrated SAS Controller, will have to check the T3400's tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [one](http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=perc) of the PERC specific plugins (or whatever RAID controller you have), you should be able to look at the dell open manage [MIBs](http://thwack.com/forums/74/tools/11/engineers-toolset/5791/dell-hardware-status-mib/) and figure out what the OIDs are. You'll need to install them in the right place so your nagios servers' snmpd can grok them anyway most likely. I do believe Open manage will send traps about pretty much any of the hardware in a Dell server.